# Equal distance between axis ticks with different jumps

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

We are working with a data frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(
  n = c(0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 100, 100, 100),
  y = c(1, 2, 1.5, NA, 2, 2.5, NA, 3, 4.5),
  f = c("i", "j", "k", "i", "j", "k", "i", "j", "k")
)
```

To create a bar plot, I wrote this code

```
colors <- c("i" = "#1F1F1F", "j" = "#606060", "k" = "#B3B3B3")
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = n, y = y, fill = f), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 3.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, labels = c("i", "j", "k"), labs(title = "Title")) +
  theme_bw()
```

It works fine but there's one problem in the position of ticks on the x-axis.

How can we have three breaks labeled `0`, `5`, and `100` but with equal distances from each other?

I tried this `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.02, 0.02), breaks=?, labels=c("0", "5", "100"))` but I'm not sure how to define `breaks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your toy data `df` mimics the real data, coercing `n` to factor might a sufficient solution. To accomplish that, all we need to change is `x = n` to `x = as.factor(n)`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  n = c(0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 100, 100, 100),
  y = c(1, 2, 1.5, NA, 2, 2.5, NA, 3, 4.5),
  f = c("i", "j", "k", "i", "j", "k", "i", "j", "k")
)
colors <- c("i" = "#1F1F1F", "j" = "#606060", "k" = "#B3B3B3")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(n), y = y, fill = f), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, labels = c("i", "j", "k"), labs(title = "Title")) +
  labs(x = "n") +
  theme_bw()
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_bar()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there a way to adjust tick numbers so it falls in the middle of two bars for each `n =5, 10`?

Comment: I think shifting those values is not a good idea. I am no `ggplot2` expert. However, perhaps there is a way to tweak that by providing a function to the `breaks` argument of `scale_x_discrete()`. Fyi, you can get the current postions like this: `p <- ggplot(...) + ...; layer_scales(p)$x$break_positions()`.